# c# Regular Expression speed issue

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regular expression in C#, where the pattern is 8000+ words (or groups of words) each separated by word boundaries, i.e.:

```
"\\bword1\\b|\\bword2 word3 word4\\b|.......etc"
```

I am trying to match a word (or group of words) in a string to any word (or group of words) in this expression. It all works fine, except I find that on average it takes 37ms to complete the operation.

Interestingly, if I do the same thing but using `String.IndexOf` and some convoluted methods it does run substantially quicker (but still far too slow), which I find odd.

I am aware of other regular expression engines in particular re2/google but am really keen to use C# built in functionality where possible.

If anyone has advice it would be appreciated.

Comment: those \b's have two slashes in real life... they just got escaped when posting!

Comment: Did you use RegexOptions.Compiled? Tohugh 8000+ Word pattern is pretty overkill i guess.

Comment: @james That's why there is a "format as code" option in the editor. ;)

Comment: Did you use the compile option in the RegexOptions? for use in the constructor, var regex= new Regex(string,RegexOptions)

Comment: That is a really weird use of regexps, why not to convert your regexp to string array/dictionary and use collection methods to search

Comment: Hi Csharpie; I tried the compiled option, but it seems to just stop on the new line of code. No error. I put try catch and round it and it didn't go into the catch. Maybe it was going to take minutes...or maybe it just bombed out somehow, I don't know.

Comment: Hi Anri, I don't think I can use an array/dictionary because of the mutiple words? For example if the input is "September New Test" and one of the phrases in the Regex pattern is "New Test" or just "Test" I would want that to match too.... or am I missing the point?

Comment: @james it probably takes a while to create the regex since it precompiles the regex to make it faster when it is used. JFYI

Comment: Thanks, I did think that, but it takes more than 30 seconds to compile and the existing way it took around 13 to run the whole thing so I don't think that's going to be an option. Thanks for taking the time though

Comment: @james, if `input="September New Test"` you can match it with `input.split(' ').Any(myHashSet.Contains)`. Where `hashSet` is build with your words/phrases in regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand why your regular expression is slow you must simply envision how regular expressions work.

In your case (8000 alternatives)

- Step 1. Start at input character 0.
- Step 2. Try to match alternative 0. Oops, no match.
- Step 3. Try to match alternative 1. Oops, no match.
- ...
- Step 4000. Try to match alternative 4001. Yay! First character matches!
- Step 4001. Try to match alternative 4001. Yay! Second character matches!
- Step 4002. Try to match alternative 4001. Oops, no match.
- Step 4003. Try to match alternative 4002. Oops, no match.
- ...
- Step 8963. Try to match alternative 7999. Oops, no match.
- Step 8964. Failed all alternatives at input character 0.
- Step 8965. Move to input character 1.
- Step 8966. Try to match alternative 0. Oops, no match.
- ...

The longer your input string is, the more alternatives your regex has and the more "almost, but not quite" matches occur in your input string, the slower this will get.

If you can make it faster with `String.IndexOf()`, do it. You will never make it faster with regex.

Explore other ways of searching strings for words. Which one would work for you strongly depends on how your input looks like.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep trying to find ways... obviously one way is to reduce the number of words in the regex but I am struggling to do that at the moment (long story)

Comment: I think you are at a point where regex no longer is a strategy worth following.

Comment: Believe this can also be called "Catastrophic Backtracking"

Comment: No, that's not catastrophic backtracking. This expression runs at optimal speed, it's just that the optimum isn't exactly fast in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest switching to [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), because it seems better suited to your task.

Here is a draft of what you could do:

```
// produce string[] containing your words
var words = myRegexp.split("\\b|\\");

var mySet = new HashSet<string>(words);
// usage
mySet.Contains("find this");
```